# Filter by entry_id parameter in exp:store:search tag

Tags: expresso-store

`{exp:store:search}` doesn't appear to allow you to filter by `entry_id` in the same way `{exp:channel:entries}` does.

I've written a plugin that will return only entries that meet advanced category criteria which works great (it returns them as a piped string of entry_ids).

However I need to pass that into `{exp:store:search}` in order to take advantage of your order by price feature.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Store search tag is actually a wrapper for channel entries, and does exactly that - it generates a list of entry IDs and passes them through, which is why it can't accept a list of entry IDs itself.

What I suggest you do instead of using the a Store search tag is simply order them yourself in your SQL statement. All you need to do is add

```
JOIN exp_store_products on exp_store_products.entry_id = exp_channel_entries.entry_id
ORDER BY exp_store_products.price ASC
```

Then pass them into the channel entries tag using the fixed_order="1|2|3" parameter (instead of entry_id=""). It works exactly the same but will preserve the order of entry IDs you pass in.